Will showing disinterest in stakeholder engagement affect my offer of admission?
A PhD advertisement mentioned that there is scope for engagement with stakeholder groups based on student interest.
I do not have previous experience of stakeholder analysis. There is so much information on the web regarding stakeholder communications plans, engagement plans, management plans. As I do not have previous experience of working with primary stakeholders, I feel this procedure could be exhausting.
My potential supervisor wants to know my attitude and approach towards communicating with stakeholders. If it is essential for my PhD funding, I will build interest in working with stakeholders. But, can it negatively impact getting PhD admission with full funding if I show a lack of knowledge or enthusiasm to engage with stakeholders?
As a side note, I have experience working in research collaborations and I do not have a problem working as a research assistant to fund my study.
But is it really exhausting to engage with stakeholder group?

Sounds like an excellent opportunity. Is this a communication or language concern?

Any position you take in your life will require ‘stakeholder engagement’ unless nobody cares about what you do. Seems like a great learning option and way to rapidly build a professional network.

I have no idea what "stakeholder engagement" means in an academic context.  Can anyone translate?

@TerryLoring, OP names WHO, which I imagine is the World Health Organization, as an example, but maybe it’s best if he or she elaborates on what the expected engagement is.

I suggest honesty with your potential supervisor. If you have no prior experience (as few of us do at that stage) say so. If you are willing to explore it and participate, say that also. A doctoral program is fundamentally a learning experience, not a professional position in which you are assumed already well qualified.
Your potential supervisor seems committed to this path. I would probably do you no good to resist it. If you really don't want to get involved in such things (a valid position IMO), then you should look elsewhere for a position as the potential conflict with a supervisor does you no good and can lead to failure.
Make a choice, but be honest.
